# Django-Leaflet in Django 1.9.4

Tags: python, django, django-templates, leaflet

I am using Django 1.9.4 and I tried to install Django-Leaflet in INSTALLED_APPS of My project. 
It installed successfully. Then in one of my apps templates, I need to show maps using Leaflet.
I followed the instructions given by Django-Leaflet. 
Like I added,

```
{% Load leaflet-tags %} {% leaflet_js %} {% leaflet_css %}
```

Then I put

```
{% block content %}
{% leaflet_map "spots" %}
{% endblock %}
```

But it throws an error;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined
```

That shows loadmap is getting an error. Please pointed out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag library is `leaflet_tags` (with an underscore `_`), not `leaflet-tags`:

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
```